# SAPUI5 Read Excel File from a folder in side the application

Tags: sapui5

I've a template excel file which stored in a folder in my application in the following path.

> webapp\template\tmp.xlsx

I need to read the content of the file without using a file uploader control.
Is there any way to read the content of a file from it's path without using a file uploader control.

Comment: as far as I know it's impossible to read local files on disk (with javascript) without the file reader.

Comment: @DubZ what I mean is not reading a local file.. I'm trying to read a file inside my webapp folder

Comment: you cant access remote files via javascript. this is only possible with a serverside programming language.
what you need is a webservice which reads, evaluates and responses the file like you want to the sapui5 app